# Left Shift In Ring Counter

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
module RingCounter(

input logic Clock,

input logic Reset,

output logic [3:0] Count

);


always_ff @(posedge Clock, posedge Reset)

begin

if (Reset) 

Count <= 4’d1;

else 

Count <= {Count[2:0], Count[3]};

end

endmodule
```

I have the working code above for a 4-bit ring counter in SystemVerilog, but I am unsure how one line of it works as it wasn't clearly explained in the lecture.

```
Count <= {Count[2:0], Count[3]};
```

Any help on explaining exactly what this line does would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly braces,  `{}`, are the concatenation operator.  They concatenate multiple bits into a bus.

On the left hand side of the nonblocking assignment (`<=`), you have `Count`, which is a short-hand way of writing the 4-bit bus: `Count[3:0]`.

On the right hand side of the assignment, you have the 3-bit signal `Count[2:0]` concatenated with the 1-bit signal `Count[3]`.

Another way to write the RHS is as 4 separate bits in the following order:

```
{Count[2], Count[1], Count[0], Count[3]}
```

Another way to write the LHS is as 4 separate bits in the following order:

```
{Count[3], Count[2], Count[1], Count[0]}
```

Therefore, the assignment sets the new `Count[3]` to the old `Count[2]`, etc.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.4.12 *Concatenation operators*.